# Is there a standard "smallest possible computer screen width"?

Tags: html, css, width, screen, screen-size

With every responsive website, there's a certain point where it would be unreasonable to allow the width of `html` to shrink any further (on a computer screen, not mobile or tablet).

Is there a certain standard number in pixels that web developers use as the smallest possible computer screen width,  which the html shouldn't be allowed to shrink below?

In other words, it would be the `min-width` of `html`, if the `width` is 100%.

Comment: StackOverflow has a `min-width` of about `1000px` (just as an example). I'd assume there's no "true" answer to this question, though; it seems very subjective.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for a min-width, we're looking for the smallest devices we're likely to encounter. So, unless we're targeting smartwatches (as @Tammo) said, in which case we'll be creating an entirely different interface optimized for the smartwatch, the devices we'll likely be looking at are smartphones.

**Android**: Android compatibility guidelines mean that, at minimum, any Android phone will be at least 240px wide ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519605/minimum-screen-resolution-for-android-devices) question lists those guidelines and a few, relatively rare examples). **Min: 240px**

**iPhone** Even the first iPhone was 320px wide, and they've only increased in resolution since then. **Min: 320px**

Considering those two minimum resolutions, the smallest resolution you're ever likely to see is 240px, though this is so rare that 320px is much more likely to be a better min-width candidate, as it gives more layout options to design a better site.

Comment: Good information, but I was just talking about computer screens.

Comment: Ah so you are - didn't notice that in the question on the first reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try and avoid any limits on the responsive design, if you find things to crush up find ways to minimize the amount of data on screen either by removing or collapsing content.