# What is the lowest screen resolution for a smartphone?

Tags: android, frontend, smartphone

What is the lowest screen resolution for a smartphone? is it 320x480 ?

Comment: Please do google, search in stackoverflow before asking question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its a duplicate question .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

nowadays after release android watch ..
minimum resolution of screen is (a smart watch) with `240 x 240` resolution

BUT Lowest Resolution is **(240 x 320)** for `smart phone`

There are a couple of phones that use this resolution including the HTC Tattoo and Wildfire. The smallest device of is the 2.55" QVGA Sony Ericsson X10 Mini.

some links of smart phone resolution 
[LINK1](http://www.binvisions.com/articles/tablet-smartphone-resolutions-screen-size-list/)
[LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4519738/3513479)

Comment: He is asking about smart phone

Comment: i ll just update my ans please wait

Answer (score 2):

Lowest resolution is `QVGA (240x320)`

Answer (score 1):

For the SmartPhone Lowest Resolution is (240 x 320).

And For The whole Android is SmartWatch lowest Resolution is (240 x 240).