# How to display android app on low resolution LED board

Tags: android, screen-resolution, scalable

I am developing an android application for a custom android powered board.
It has 64x64 LED display. While running the app I can see only a few part of application. How can I display properly on the LED board?

Comment: Is this display acting as the main screen of the device, or as a secondary screen? If it's the main screen then 64x64 is way too low a resolution

Comment: Related - [Minimum screen resolution for Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519605/minimum-screen-resolution-for-android-devices)

Comment: @MichaelDodd its the main screen

Comment: Yeah that's way too small then. Android was never designed to run on a resolution that low.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you state that your screen size is 64x64 pixels. This screen size is well below the minimum resolution required for Android, which is why you only see part of the app. Taking Android 6.0 as an example, section 7.1.1.1 of the [Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/6.0/android-6.0-cdd.pdf) states that the minimum required resolution is 426dp x 320dp:

> Devices MUST have screen sizes of at least 426 dp x 320 dp (‘small’), unless it is an Android Watch device.

It's also not possible to use 1:1 screen ratios, with the exception of Android Watch devices:

> The screen aspect ratio MUST be a value from 1.3333 (4:3) to 1.86 (roughly 16:9), but Android Watch devices MAY have an aspect ratio of 1.0 (1:1) because such a device implementation will use a `UI_MODE_TYPE_WATCH` as the `android.content.res.Configuration.uiMode`.